# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" when trying to run ESLint script

Tags: node.js, eslint, npm-scripts, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb

I’m having issues when trying to run a lint script
`"lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx .”` `npm run lint:fix`

I keep getting this error prompted and it only seems to have come about since updating my eslint deps in line with the airbnb rules (I used `npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb`)

Error:

```
/Users/ME/Projects/MYPROJECT/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js:93
        } catch {
                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

However, running the following works as expected: `npx eslint specific/file.js —fix`

This is my .eslintrc file:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2020": true
    },
    "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": ["react"],
    "rules": {}
}
```

And these are my current eslint deps:

```
    "eslint": "7.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.21.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.1.2",
    "eslint-watch": "3.1.2",
```

Any help would be great!   Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Optional catch binding](https://v8.dev/features/optional-catch-binding) was introduced in ES2019.

The specified ESLint version should be used with Node version that [supports it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Browser_compatibility) (10 or later).

Comment: changing my ecmaVersion to 2019 still seems to have this issue.  Any ideas what the problem may be?

Comment: Sorry, was in the middle of editing. The problem is that Node version is too old for this ESLint  ersion.

Comment: No problem!  I'm also using node v12.18.4

Comment: The error clearly suggests that the problem is in Node itself. This may happen if there are multiple Node versions for some reason, this may depend on your environment. Make sure this specific command uses the one you expect, `node -e "console.log(process.execPath,process.version)" && node node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js .`. Alternatively, a plain way is to edit (and then revert it) node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js and do `console.log(process.execPath,process.version)` there.

Comment: You're right!  It was a node issue, not an eslint problem!  The version in node in package.json vs the version I had running locally were years apart!  Thanks a lot for your help!!